# SQL where clause uses MAX Effective Date and NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I'm using a backend software to run SQL on Oracle. I need to fetch the latest row based on effective date.

Here's an example table

```
Table "ACCOUNTS"
Application | Sub_category | Account_Reference | Effective_date
BC_ONLINE   | F            | ABC1234           | 01-JAN-13
BC_ONLINE   | B            | ABC2345           | 01-JAN-13
TE_Notice   | (NULL)       | 1234ABC           | 01-JAN-13
TE_Notice   | (NULL)       | 9876DEF           | 01-APR-13
```

The software will pass in two parameters: Application and Sub_category, if I used the following SQL, on the following Application: **BC_ONLINE** and Sub_category: **F**

```
select a.Account_Reference
from   ACCOUNTS a
where  a.Application = 'BC_ONLINE'
and    a.Sub_category = 'F'
and    a.Effective_date = (select max(b.Effective_date)
                           from   ACCOUNTS b
                           where  b.Effective_date <= sysdate
                           and    b.Application = a.Application
                           and    b.Sub_category = a.Sub_category)
```

BUT should I use the following Application: **TE_Notice** and Sub_category: **NULL**
and you cannot have this

```
and    a.Sub_category = null
```

since it must be

```
and    a.Sub_category is null
```

the trouble is the software is fixed, so what is the best way to use both value and null in where clause using max(effective_date)?

I have tried this method, but it doesn't work

```
select a.Account_Reference
from   ACCOUNTS a
where  a.Application = 'TE_Notice'
and    (a.Sub_category = '' or a.Sub_category is null)
and    a.Effective_date = (select max(b.Effective_date)
                           from   ACCOUNTS b
                           where  b.Effective_date <= sysdate
                           and    b.Application = a.Application
                           and    NVL(b.Sub_category,-1) = NVL(a.Sub_category,-1))
```

It simply returned the row with **01-APR-13**, but I should be getting the row with the Effective_date on **01-JAN-13**.

Comment: Your query gives me `1234ABC`, which is the `01-JAN-13` account reference - so not sure what the problem is. However, I think the fourth line should be `and (a.Sub_category = '' or ('' is null and a.Sub_category is null))` to compare properly - otherwise if you pass a non-null value it'll still match nulls in the data.

Comment: Now I know where I was going wrong - I missed out the `<= sysdate`! but @AlexPoole, you're right, the fourth line improvement is required. I've been concerned about this, didn't know how to better phrase that line. Appreciate it.

Comment: What is the expected output? A single row with max date or more...?

Comment: @Art The expected output is a single row with the max date <= sysdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @AlexPoole the SQL I put in the question is actually correct, but needed polishing.

If I adopted the following:

```
and (a.Sub_category = '' or a.Sub_category is null)
```

The select will fetch null rows as well as the non-null value, so need to improve;

```
and (a.Sub_category = '' or ('' is null and a.Sub_category is null))
```

The overall SQL should be

```
select a.Account_Reference
from   ACCOUNTS a
where  a.Application = @Application
and    (a.Sub_category = @Sub_category or (@Sub_category is null and a.Sub_category is null))
and    a.Effective_date = (select max(b.Effective_date)
                           from   ACCOUNTS b
                           where  b.Effective_date <= sysdate
                           and    b.Application = a.Application
                           and    NVL(b.Sub_category,-1) = NVL(a.Sub_category,-1))
```

Comment: David Aldridge's approach is still better (IMO) because you only hit the table once; you just need to add the `sysdate` check and the amended `sub_category` check. (And your overall SQL is missing a closing bracket on line 4 *8-)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 select account_reference
 from   (
        select   a.Account_Reference
        from     ACCOUNTS a
        where    a.Application = 'BC_ONLINE'
        and      a.Sub_category = 'F'
        and      a.effective_date <= sysdate
        order by a.Effective_date desc)
 where  rownum = 1
```

Comment: That's a better version of the first query, but doesn't handle the supplied parameter being null?

Comment: What if the `a.Sub_category is NULL`? It's a fixed software application, so the SQL should work for both cases; `a.Sub_category = 'F'` or `a.Sub_category is null`

Comment: Wouldn't work if there is a row with a much older effective_date?

Comment: @Joshua - much older, or much newer? The `order by ... desc` means the latest matching row will be returned first, so it's handling older data. But it is missing the `sysdate` check to exclude future rows - that's trivial to add back in though.